# c# automation stop process

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, process

I have C# automation code that start a process

```
 var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();

    string anyCommand = " adb logcat - v threadtime emulator-5554 > logcat.log";
    proc1.UseShellExecute = true;

    proc1.WorkingDirectory = outputDirectory;

    proc1.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    proc1.Verb = "runas";
    proc1.Arguments = "/c " + anyCommand;
    proc1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = proc1;
    p.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
    TestLogger.WriteInformationStep("p.Id: " + p.Id);
```

after some steps I'm trying to read the file

```
        string text2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(element);
```

but I receive error message

> System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Users\test\Documents\overview9\bin\Debug\Results\logcat.log'
> because it is being used by another process. TearDown :
> HarVE.Log.FailedStepException : There were 1 failed step(s): Test did
> not run to completion

what should i do?
I tried `p.Close();p.Kill();`
non of them work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If p.Kill(); where placed after System.IO.File.ReadAllText(element); write p.Kill() before System.IO.File.ReadAllText(element),
if it placed correctly, then seems like other process is reading/writting that file,
try to use StreamReader from System.IO, StreamReader can read multiple times, something like this:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path_to_file);//replace path_to_file by your txt file path
 string text2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
```